# How do I auto-deploy a web application using TFS 2010?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, continuous-integration, build-automation

I have a web app in repository in TFS. I have set up a build process (CI) from it which outputs to the web root of a site hosted by my local IIS instance. However each time the build finishes I end up with a folder under the root folder of the IIS website I'd like the built codebase to go to. So the root folder for `MyTestProject` is located at:

```
`c:\websites\MyTestProject`
```

and the build outputs to a share of this same folder `\\myPc\MyTestProject`

What I would like is for the latest build to always end up in the root folder of the site, but after a build I end up with this sort of thing:

```
`c:\websites\MyTestProject\MyTestProject_<date>.<version no>`
`c:\websites\MyTestProject\MyTestProject_<date>.<version no>/_PublishedWebsites/MyTestProject`
`c:\websites\MyTestProject\MyTestProject_<date>.<version no>/_PublishedWebsites/MyTestProject`
```

I can't seem to find a way of configuring this correctly in the build definition and struggling to find docs. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: There's no product named TFS 2012 yet. Which product are you referring to?

Comment: See many of the articles at http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss

Comment: @JohnSaunders - indeed there isn't. Corrected.

Comment: I build to a fileshare then XCOPY the output files to our web server - I prefer that anyway as it gives me the option to once-over the output files without pushing them to prod.

Comment: How did you setup an your output to copy it to the web root of the IIS site?

Answer (score 1):

I created a [blog post](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/12/Auto-deployment-of-my-web-application-with-Team-Build-2010-to-add-Interactive-Testing.aspx) on this a while ago. It was based on the [blog posts of Vishal Joshi](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'm not (at this point anyway) deploying to a remote box, just to a network server for testing so I don't really want to go the web deploy route. Can this process be tweaked to do a straight Xcopy style deploy?

Comment: It is of course its running IIS. For this branch of my app code I just want to do a straight publish to a network location instead of the web deploy shenanigans.